# Where do I find datasheets of zeolites?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics

I'm looking into uses of zeolites as water absorbers for heat storage and absorbtion cooling. However, I don't find hard numbers on the likes of absorption enthalpies at different temperatures, saturation moistures, etc.

I'm not an institution, chemical suppliers are traditionally reluctant to sell to private individuals. I found zeolitic absorbers in few catalogues, but only with a descriptor of the type, no further data. One company I asked (that sell zeolites in amounts of kg to private customers) was unwilling to share data on their product (They're an engineering company doing product developement with zeolitic absorbers for heating/cooling etc.).

I only found (sketchy) data on single zeolites in working papers, but no comprehensive source.

So: seeing that vendors don't share the info, where do I find datasheets of zeolites?

Comment: These data are time-consuming to compile together and expensive to produce. You might get lucky and find a Handbook having what you want, perhaps "Handbook of Zeolite Science and Technology" ?

Comment: found the TOC, http://www.crcnetbase.com/isbn/9780824740207 doesn't suggest datasheets. Still, answering as an answer and not as a comment would be more in the spirit of this site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've searched for this same data.  My interest regards electronic proporties of zeolite-class media.  [I've written this same kind of question on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Water-Purification/What-sources-exist-to-learn-about-materials-products-and-by-products-used-as-absorbing-flocking-agents-in-water-purification-and-metals-reclamation).

I think the reason this is rarely answered, and why there are no 'catalogs', is several-fold:

1. There exist a wide range of applications, based on the composition
   of the water / etc.
2. The treatment media usually varies in
   composition, meaning that no directive for the use of a zeolite
   product can be given by a sales rep (only on-staff engineers, who
   know how to use it).
3. Some uses create by-products that are regulated, creating possible liabilities for the seller by indicating a fitness-for-use.
4. Regulations change; per year, per locale, etc.

I think the groups that know about these are environmental engineering firms, whom have a stable of engineers that provide end-to-end services for their clientele.  Many of of these firms have Chemists on-staff, or a consultancy relationship that suits the same.  They know the chemical properties of their media, and need a zeolite / catalysts that can effect something *very* specific.  As a result, they're out their hunting the journals for something that targets their needs.

Hard to out-sell that without already having a dog in the game.